# How to import from one directory to another

Tags: python-3.x

I have two folder A and B in a folder MAIN. In these two folders A and B there is two different python module ONE in A and TWO in B. Here ONE and TWO are two different python module in different folder. Actually I want to import the all facility from TWO to ONE. Then how can i do this? Please help me.....

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Is the script you are running in folder A or in folder MAIN? Could you provide more detail on how the project is layed out and which scripts are running and importing from what. [This might help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14132912/9590327)

Comment: Actually my script is in folder A and folder A is inside Folder MAIN. Here MAIN is parent folder for A and B.

Comment: So their is no script in the MAIN folder? I would suggest moving ONE into MAIN and then (with an empty __init__.py file in B) in A write `from B import TWO`. If there is a script in MAIN and ONE is imported into that script the same code should work. If this works I'll write a full answer on it explaining why

Comment: But I don't want to do this. Actually I am working on a project and if I do so then my project layout will be lengthy to work.   That's why I only do this that way

Comment: Sorry then but the only other why I can think of is to use the absolute path [see this this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path). Although I cannot see why adding a script into main just saying `from A import ONE` would be a problem